# I have a large number of attributes in magento 1.9 won't save

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, position

I am trying to change the position of my attributes. There are a lot of attributes it says it saves the position, but nothing happens. No position is changed.

I am a bit lost how to solve this.

Comment: Existing or newly added attributes? Did you clear all cache?

Comment: How many attributes do you have?

Comment: They are existing attributes. The shop is communicating with a cash register in a physical shop. There are approx 1200 size attributes. A bit much. But this is how the cash register works. Stock in the webshop corresponds with stock in the physical shop.

Cache is completely cleared. 
max_input_vars is set on 2000

Comment: If it's about a large number of attribute **options**, there are a few possible limitations: maximum input vars, maximum request length, and last but not least the client CPU because of a huge amount of DOM & JavaScript. To solve these problems all at once, we developed an extension that adds pagination to the attribute option page. It's open source on GitHub: https://github.com/integer-net/IntegerNet_AttributeOptionPager

Answer (score 3):

We've had this issue twice before. This happend to us on an **attribute options page** with lots of attribute values as well as on the payment methods page where we had a lot of input field for various payment methods.

In our case it was in both cases the [Apache 2.2 `MaxRequestLen`](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) (`FcgidMaxRequsetLen` in Apache 2.4) setting. 
The hosting providers changed the default value to a lower value which was actually too low for our Magento installations which had this big amount of input fields.